# I am not able to pass themultiple data php array to json string list ."subnet_name":"[\"phpsubnet\",\"testsubnet\"]",

Tags: php, arrays, json, list

I need to pass the multiple data in one json list
Sample payload

```
"resourcegroup_name":"phpvnet",
"location":"Centralus",
"virtual_network_name":"demophpvnet",
"vnetAddressPrefix":"10.0.0.0/16",
"subnet_count":"2",
"subnet_name":"[\"phpsubnet\",\"testsubnet\"]",
"address_prefix":"[\"10.0.1.0/24\",\"10.0.2.0/24\"]"
```

and the php and json data i am passing is

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){

    $provisionId = "cloudknit".substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 6);
    $rgname = $_POST['rgname'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $vnetname = $_POST['vnetname'];
    $vnetaddress = $_POST['vnetaddress'];
    $subnetcount = $_POST['subnetcount'];
    $subnetname = $_POST['subnetname'];
    $addressprefix = $_POST['addressprefix'];

      echo json_encode(array($col,$col2));

      $data = array(
      "provisionId"=>"$provisionId",
      "resourcegroup_name"=>"$rgname",
      "location"=>"$location",
      "virtual_network_name"=>"$vnetname",
      "vnetAddressPrefix"=>"$vnetaddress",
      "subnet_count"=>"$subnetcount",
      "subnet_name"=>"$subnetname",
      "address_prefix"=>"$addressprefix"
      );
```

I need to pass the data  from php to json list in subnet name and address prefix.

Comment: What's your question / problem? Is there an issue with your above code? Please describe the issue as well as just stating your goal

Comment: Hi ADyson, I need to pass the data from Input box which will be phpsubnet,testsubnet and it should be in a format  "subnet_name":"[\"phpsubnet\",\"testsubnet\"]",

Comment: Ok. And what is the problem exactly with doing that? Also, why do you want to put the data into that double-encoded string format? That's not a good approach. It would be much better to have a single coherent JSON object

Comment: So the sample payload is like that we can't change the payload type just tell me how e can pass from php

Comment: Well what have you tried? Just explode the incoming comma-separated string, then encode the resulting array as JSON, then assign it to the relevant property of your payload object. It's a bit of a naff API though if it requires data in such a strange format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use json_decode() function first to convert the string to a PHP list/array then you can assign the returned value to "subnet_name" field in your new array,I hope this piece of code would help you:

```
<?php
          
$subnetname="[\"phpsubnet\",\"testsubnet\"]";
$json = [
   'subnetname'  => json_decode($subnetname)
];

var_dump($json);
```

EDITTED:

```
$data = array( "provisionId"=>"$provisionId", 
"resourcegroup_name"=>"$rgname", 
"location"=>"$location", 
"virtual_network_name"=>"$vnetname", 
"vnetAddressPrefix"=>"$vnetaddress", 
"subnet_count"=>$subnetcount, 'subnetname' => explode(",", $subnetname), 
"address_prefix"=>"$addressprefix" 
);
```

Comment: Hi, how do i pass from php there is an input box from there I used to post it so if I had to pass these name should I pass phpsubnet,testsubnet

Comment: it would be better; and in that case use this: <?php
              
$subnetname="phpsubnet,testsubnet";

$json = [
    'subnetname'  => explode(",", $subnetname)
];

var_dump($json);

Comment: $data = array(
      "provisionId"=>"$provisionId",
      "resourcegroup_name"=>"$rgname",
      "location"=>"$location",
      "virtual_network_name"=>"$vnetname",
      "vnetAddressPrefix"=>"$vnetaddress",
      "subnet_count"=>"$subnetcount",
      $json = [
        'subnetname'  => explode(",", $subnetname)
      ],
      var_dump($json),
      "address_prefix"=>"$addressprefix"
      );

$curl = curl_init();

Comment: Check the above block

Comment: its correct or not please check

Comment: Please check the code is correct or not the var_dump($json) is correct place inside $data

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect, refer to my edited response in the main thread.

Comment: if that helped you out, you can mark this as solved

Answer (score 1):

I just got an answer. if you want the string in json encode format whenever the json has multiple data list use this

'''

```
  $json = [
    'subnet_name'  => json_encode(explode(",", $subnetname))
  ];
  
  $json1 = [
    'address_prefix'  =>  json_encode($addres_fix, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
  ];
```

'''

Comment: what about upvoting the above answer too :)